# Filter Postgres Json array is subset of array using JsonPath

Tags: postgresql, jsonpath

I fail to find any information on how to do `in` / `subsetof` / `contains` queries using JsonPath in Postgres.

e.g.
Assuming the following data in a jsonb column named `data`

```
{
   "name": "foo",
   "somearray" : [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Then I want to query this using something like

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
where jsonb_path_exists(data, '($.somearray ??????? [2,4,6,8] ');
```

This does work:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
where jsonb_path_exists(data, '($ ? (@.somearray[*] == 2 || @.somearray[*] == 4 /*etc*/) ');
```

But I am hoping that there is some shorter syntax to do a proper subset test

Comment: I don't think there is any support for that. You would need to write your own code. Or normalize your data model to a state where you don't need to use JSON any more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no [jsonpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-OP-TABLE) array operators, but you can still use the [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
where (data->>'somearray') :: integer[] @> [2,4,6,8] ;
```

Comment: Many thanks, I find it somewhat odd that a Json query language does not support this. but I will go with your solution instead. 